# Laravel development structure

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I am developing an application in which I have views for different roles.

For example, I have a form which has 5 fields. It may have 3 fields for role 1 and all fields for role 5 available when submitting.

Now, where I am showing the form data as graphically or using table, I have options to show 5 columns or fields for some role and less fields form for some other role.

Right now I am doing if else logic in each action of controller to determine the role then pass the appropriate data to the view, how do you manage this? I would like to know.

PLEASE READ FULL BEFORE SAYING 'SHOW ME SOME CODE :('

EDIT:
1 more question, suppose there is a users class and have a 1 to 1 relation with type class, in the views i can do:

```
{{ Auth::user()->type->key }}
```

Or some complex ones like

```
{{ Auth::user()->as_member->claims->sum('amount_claimed') }}
```

This is a complex relation, user as a member have many claims and I am summing it up here. Is it better to do this in controller then pass them as a value?

Comment: better to do logic in controllers rather than in views and doing in repositories  is even better.

Comment: Can you delete your second question and post it on a second post?

Answer (score 0):

Generally speaking User and Role share Many-To-Many relation. A user can have many roles and a role can be shared by many users.

To implement it three database tables are required
1. users
2. roles
3. role_user (pivot table)

Then the relation could be defined in the models as

```
class User extends Model
{
    public function roles()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany('App\Roles');
    } 

    //suppose you currently want to assign each user only one role
    //however also want to provision multiple roles for user in future
    //then you can define a virtual/calculated attribute to your model
    //to simplify usage considering each user has only one role

    public function getRoleAttribute()
    {
        return $this->roles[0]->name;  //name is a field on the roles table
    }  

    protected $appends = ['role'];  //to ensure that the calculated attribute is available to ajax/json/api requests as well

}


class Role extends Model
{
    public function users()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany('App\User');
    }
}
```

Say you have three users as sample data

User1 has role 'User'

User2 has role 'Manager'

User3 has role 'Admin'

Now you can test the functionality with a sample view like

```
<h4>Current user is {{auth()->user()->name}} having a role of {{auth()->user()->role}}</h4>

<div class="example-form">
    <h4 class="all">Visible to all - User1, User2, User3</h4>  
    @if( (auth()->user()->role ==='Manager') || (auth()->user()->role ==='Admin'))
         <h4>Visible to Manager and Admin only - User2 and User3</h4>
    @endif
    @if(auth()->user()->role === 'Admin')
         <h4>Visible only to Administrator - User3</h4>
    @endif
</div>
```

Hope this is what you are aiming for  - is my understanding okay.

However since you have mentioned that you are using Laravel 5.2, better way of doing it would be to use out-of-box authorization provided by Laravel 5.2.

Refer [Authorization documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/authorization)